# Footer with 3 columns, right and left fixed, center fluid maximized

Tags: html, css, footer, fixed-width

I would obtain a 3 column footer with fixed width left and right column and the central fill the remaining space:

.
.
.
|[LEFT]<------central------>[RIGHT]|

Now I'm using this code, but the central column has fixed width :(

```
.left  
{  
  float:left;  
  width: 100px;  
}  
.central  
{  
  float:left;  
  width: {xxx}px  
}  
.right  
{  
  float:right;  
  width: 100px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your source order, you can continue using floats but only for the left and right elements:

http://tinker.io/99f07/2

```
.left  
{  
  float:left;  
  width: 100px;  
}  
.central  
{  
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}  
.right  
{  
  float:right;  
  width: 100px;  
}  

<div class="left">
    Left
</div>

<div class="right">
    Right
</div>

<div class="central">
    Lorem ipsum dolor...
</div>
```

Otherwise, changing the display type of all 3 sibling elements to table-cell will do the job (as an added benefit, the elements are now equal height):

http://tinker.io/99f07/1

```
/* optional
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}*/

.left  
{  
  display: table-cell;  
  width: 100px;  
}  
.central  
{  
  display: table-cell;  
}  
.right  
{  
  display: table-cell;  
  width: 100px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

CSS:

```
.left  
{  
  float:left;  
  width: 100px;
}  
.central  
{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;   
}  
.right  
{  
  float: right;    
  width: 100px;
}
```

and your HTML must be in this order (left, right and central) to work:

```
<div class="left">test</div>    
<div class="right">test</div>
<div class="central">test</div>
```

I wrote "test" just to see the results. =)

Hugs,
Vin.

Comment: The OP wants the central column to be a fluid width, not fixed.

Comment: Try to replace central width of 100px to 100%. It worked here.

Comment: Because I have a border in each div I've used:    width: 100%;
  margin-left: 100px; margin-right: 100px;  for the central div Thanks

Comment: @willygroup Wait, how does that make sense?  My solution has right/left margins, but you accepted this answer which does not?

Comment: @cimmanon probably I didn't see 
 your answer (It was posted a bunch of minutes before mine). :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qtzKk/

Use absolute positioning and the `left` and `right` attributes if you want a fixed width for your left and right hand divs.

You can wrap it with a relative positioned div so it's not overlapped by your site content.

Comment: Absolute positioning does not play nicely with content where the size is unknown.

Comment: It does in his case if he wants fixed width on the two outer divs. And as I said before. He can size the wrapper around the 3 divs any way he likes.

Comment: Only the width is known here, not the height.  What happens when the contents are taller than the viewport?  It gets cut off.

Comment: Again... It doesn't if you wrap it with a relative positioned div with whatever height you like. You can even scroll them if you like... You're completely free to modify to your choosing.